# Cannot find #unwrap macro in Xcode Version 15.0 beta (15A5160n)

Tags: swift, xcode15, swift-macro

Apple demonstrated in more than one session the `#unwrap` macro which I thought I built into Xcode 15 and the frameworks it is shipped with directly.

But if I try to unwrap an URL:

```swift
let url = #unwrap(URL(string: "my-awsome-url.tld"))
```

I get the error:

```
No macro named 'unwrap'
```

I checked the tutorial app of the WWDC'23 called "[Backyard Birds](https://github.com/apple/sample-backyard-birds)" and there is no `#unwrap`. This leads to my conclusion that the `#unwrap()` macro does not really exists and it is just a "tutorial"? Hm, but I think the macro would be really helpful.